# confluence install troubles

Tags: wiki, jira, confluence

I just managed to get the install on my server (win server 2008/sql server 2008)

http://prjatk.com:8090

Something has gone badly wrong as is imediately visible from the home page!!

Anyone have any ideas? This is a paid for installation.

w://

Comment: Does your "paid for" installation include support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the isapi re-write module in IIS needed to run confluence under IIS:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942076

This was not something atlassian would help with paid for or not :(

FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it just looks like your css is missing.

> This is a paid for installation.

Well then call Atlassian support. They have very knowledgable and helpful people in their support department. I've called them many times for issues with Confluence and JIRA. You're paying for the support...so use it!